# NextJs handle logic for request pre-processing & post-processing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js

In NextJs unlike other frameworks it doesn't provide filter chain or request pre-processing or post processing.
This could be a common need for any node project or some library developers to have their logic to be executed before and after actual call delegated to API endpoint / Web pages.

```
Kind of this feature available in express other js framework.
Request 
  ---------> | pre-interceptor  | ------> 
                                                API /Pages
 <-----------| post-interceptor| <-----
Response
```

In NextJS middleware provides a way with limited feature(Edge Runtime) for request pre-processing but that can't be used for request post-processing.

Above mentioned scenario can be handled with custom express server which provides handle() & next() function to control the flow.
If I go with custom server on my own infra, am I losing any optimization or performance stuff?

Any idea how to deal with it next server?

Answer (score 0):

In short, Next.js provides the following options for request pre-processing and post-processing:

1. API Routes
2. Middleware (for pre-processing only, with limitations)
3. Serverless Functions and Edge Functions (if deploying on Vercel)
4. List item

Using a custom Express server is possible but may impact performance and optimizations provided by Next.js's built-in server. It's generally recommended to explore the built-in Next.js options first before considering a custom server.
Next js doc for custom server: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server

one of my implementation in project :
https://github.com/jaysparmar/next-node